# Translate matlab fminsearchbnd in R?

Tags: r, matlab, optimization

I am trying to translate a Matlab code to R, finding the minmum error of two functions.

Here is the Matlab code:

```
erro=@(x) sum(((f14.*x(2)./(((x(1))/0.9924)+x(5))-(f14.*x(2)./(((x(1))/0.9924)+x(5))-x(3)).*exp(-(((x(1))/0.9924)+x(5))*(t-t1)))-mo).^2)./std(mo)+ sum (((f15.*x(2)./((x(1)+x(5)))-(f15.*x(2)./((x(1)+x(5)))-x(4)).*exp(-((x(1)+x(5))).*(t-t1)))-no).^2)/std(no); 

x=fminsearchbnd(erro,xo,[0 0 200 0.9 0],[])

% x = 0.0123128476186327    13.5174782795704    368.926386686419    76.4422946745777    8.28109088192835e-09
```

So i tried the pracma-package first, unfortunately I could find fminbnd() and fminsearch() function, but no fminsearchbnd(). Is there a way to combine these two? Or can anyone think of different solutions?
I tried the optim() function with "method = c("L-BFGS-B") and it gave me the best results so far. However I wonder if there is a way to get exact the same results in Matlab and R.

My translation to R:

```
t <- c(0.5, 1, 2, 3)
mo <- c(368.54, 374.04, 381.75, 390.92)
no <- c(76.46, 75.96, 75.14, 74.23)
f15 <- c(0.003431)  
f14 <- c(1-f15)    
xo <-  c(0.01211952, 13.30265, 368.54, 76.46, -0.000504064)


erro <- function(x){sum(((f14*x[2]/(((x[1])/0.9924)+x[5])-(f14*x[2]/(((x[1])/0.9924)+x[5])-x[3])*exp(-(((x[1])/0.9924)+x[5])*(t-t[1])))-mo)^2)/std(mo) 
  + sum (((f15*x[2]/((x[1]+x[5]))-(f15*x[2]/((x[1]+x[5]))-x[4])*exp(-((x[1]+x[5]))*(t-t[1])))-no)^2)/std(no)} 

x <- optim(xo, erro, lower = c(0, 0, 200, 0.9, 0), method = c("L-BFGS-B"))
# $par
#[1]   0.01230393  13.30265160 368.54000000  76.44231900   0.00000000
```

Thanks for your help and please forgive any mistakes, this is my first post and I have no idea about matlab! ;)

Update:
I wanted to compare the optim-results with those from MATLAB for different values, so I tried with:

```
mo <- c(322.79, 327.06, 323.11, 322.60)
no <- c(70.01023605, 64.18709552, 59.03694208, 55.83444661)
lo <- c(0.2573, 0.2525, 0.2398, 0.2388)
xo <- c(0.07856273, 24.87679, 322.79, 70.01024, 0.03182682)
```

I got the error 'L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'' so I set my first bound up from 0 to 0.00001, resulting in:

```
[1,] 1e-05 24.91 322.79 68.59785 0.09070217
```

However, my first value always sticks to the lower bound, whereas Matlab results are:

```
0.05460 28.88570 324.74040 68.58710 0.03620
```

Comment: There is no function `fminsearchbnd` in pure MATLAB; also, there is no `std` in Base R! For minimizing a function with bound constraints `optim` is a reasonable choice, but there are many more such optimizers, see the Optimization task view. If your function has many local minima, the results may not always be the same. (BTW: Your MATLAB code is not reproducible.)

Answer (score 1):

The region where the minimum lives is *very* flat. Therefore, to get good results in R, one could add an explicit numerical gradient, as the gradient used by `optim()` may not be accurate enough. Here we employ the gradient function from the 'numDeriv' package.

```
f15 <- c(0.003431); f14 <- c(1-f15)
t <- c(0.5, 1, 2, 3)

mo <- c(322.79, 327.06, 323.11, 322.60)
no <- c(70.01023605, 64.18709552, 59.03694208, 55.83444661)
lo <- c(0.2573, 0.2525, 0.2398, 0.2388)

# starting parameters
xo <- c(0.07856273, 24.87679, 322.79, 70.01024, 0.03182682)

erro <- function(x){
    sum(((f14*x[2]/(((x[1])/0.9924)+x[5])-(f14*x[2]/(((x[1])/0.9924)+x[5])-x[3])*exp(-(((x[1])/0.9924)+x[5])*(t-t[1])))-mo)^2)/sd(mo) + sum (((f15*x[2]/((x[1]+x[5]))-(f15*x[2]/((x[1]+x[5]))-x[4])*exp(-((x[1]+x[5]))*(t-t[1])))-no)^2)/sd(no)
} 

# minimum value at MATLAB solution xm
xm <- c(0.05460, 28.88570, 324.74040, 68.58710, 0.03620)
erro(xm)
## [1] 6.367856

# numerical gradient
erro_gr <- function(x) numDeriv::grad(erro, x)

s <- optim(xo, erro, gr = erro_gr,
           lower = c(1.e-07, 0, 200, 0.9, 0),
           method = c("L-BFGS-B"))
s$par;s$value
## [1] 0.08281183 28.97220 324.7395 68.58882 0.008001717
## [1] 6.367579
```

This is even smaller than the MATLAB solution 6.367856, see above.